# One IP address and two subdomains possible on IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

**Background**

I'm using a single server in my home network that runs Windows SBS 2011. It services Active Directory, IIS7 and DNS services.

Currently I can change how my domain (mydomain.com) looks on the Internet using the "Default Web Site" website. However when I create additional websites (blog.mydomain.com) in IIS Manager, they are not showing up on the Internet.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to set up two subdomains with 1 IP address in Windows IIS7?

Can I make it so www.mydomain.com and blog.mydomain.com are both public on the Internet?

**Question 2:** How do I go about setting up the subdomain blog.mydomain.com?

In IIS Manager, I'm using Sites > Default Web Site for www.mydomain.com files. This is working for me and I can create and set up index.html and build the website.

For the subdomain, after I add a website, what settings do I need to change:
- What settings do I need to have for the website
- What records do I need on the server DNS
- What records do I need on the domain DNS
- What other settings do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be accomplished.

You use the "Bindings..." option In IIS7 for configuring the domain/subdomain for each website.

This is a way you could set it up:

- Make sure you have two websites in IIS7. One is set to the root of your website directory, another one set to the root directory of your blog platform.
- Your website has the binding configured like this:
  www.mydomain.com using Port 80
- The blog site has the binding configured like this:
  blog.mydomain.com using Port 80

Comment: Do you mean creating 2 websites in IIS Manager under "Sites"? I created two (www, blog) but neither of the pages are displaying. Do I need to make any changes on the server DNS or domain DNS?

Comment: Yes. If you have not setup the domain names in the DNS server to point to your web server, you will not be able to view the site. You could add a temporary binding to each website, for instance, try adding a binding for port 81 (without a domain name) in IIS bindings and then click Browse in IIS7. You can also open Internet Explorer and go to http:// localhost:81 (without space). This will ensure that your website actually works, but it won't be accessible from the outside.

Comment: Regarding your reply to Cosmin Onea, I think you should Remove the defaultRedirect parameter from your web.config file. It's easier to use the IIS7 manager rather than editing the file manually. I don't think the redirect is what you are looking for here. Perhaps you meant DefaultDocument? I suggest stopping the website in IIS7 manager, rename web.config to web.config.bk as a backup, start the site, add the default document you will be using and see if IIS have generated a new web.config file for you without the faulty config.

Comment: If I remove the web.config file, then there is an error saying that the config file is missing and IIS does not generate it for me automatically. The error page gives an example config that should be there which is what I've put into the web.config file currently.

I've updated the server DNS to include host a new zone and matching PTR record for blog.mydomain.com, where the A record points to the server address (DNS/web/AD). I've also added an A record in the domain DNS that points "blog" to the external IP address (same IP address as default www).

Comment: Nslookup and tracert both resolve blog.mydomain.com to the server address as specified in the DNS. Now going to blog.mydomain.com in a web browser, the browser is just stuck on "Waiting for blog.mydomain.com" and does not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: yes

Q2: Create two websites, ignore the default web site. One for www and the other for blog. On the new website screen specify the Host Name accordingly, i.e. www.mydomain.com for the first site and blog.mydomain.com for the second. Keep the port 80 for both. Later you can change these settings in the website Bindings screen.

What this basically does it associates names with different websites so when requests come to your server on the same IP IIS knows to which website to dispatch the request.

The default website in IIS, because it has no Host Name, will handle all the requests that are neither for www or blog subdomains.

Comment: So for example I've tried creating a new website with hostname www.mydomain.com, with an index page and a web.config file containing:
`<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="index.html"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`

Now I get an error 500 - Internal server error.

What else am I missing?